# I wanted to calculate Even numbers and number of Uppercase letters in a string?

Tags: python

```
import re
msg = input("Please type: ")
print("Capital Letters: ", sum(1 for c in msg if c.isupper()))
a = re.findall(',*\d*[02468]',msg)
print (a)
```

# OUTPUT:
    Please type: dfg2468789fghHHH
    Capital Letters:  3
    ['246878']

Comment: ** For example: if user input: " AMITamit1234" the output must be 
Uppercase: 4 and  Even number: 2 4 **
if input is 246898 i am only getting 2468 but not the last 8. Can anyone help

Comment: ** I wanted this output **Please type: dfg2468789fghHHH** 
Capital Letters: 3 
even number: ['2 4 6 8 8']

Comment: Change your regex from `,*\d*[02468]` to `,*[02468]` to capture even numbers.

Comment: Why do you need regex for this?

Comment: `uppercase = len([x for x in msg if x.isupper()]) even_numbers = [y for y in filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), msg) if int(y) % 2 == 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
message = input('Please type: ')


capitals = (sum(1 for c in message if c.isupper()))

even = ['0','2','4','6','8']
evennumbers = []
for x in range(0,len(message)):
    if message[x] in even:
        evennumbers.append(message[x])

evens = ''
for x in range(0,len(evennumbers)):
    evens = evens + str(evennumbers[x])

capitals = str(capitals)
evens = "['" + evens + "']"

print('Capitals : ' + capitals, evens)
```

Comment: I dont know know why its down voted. 
your answer solved the problem. 
Thank you so much Imaad

Comment: No problem the `evens = ['" + evens + "']` line is optional, I only put that in because its want you wanted the output to look like. If you have remove that line it will just be the numbers without it looking like its in a list.

Comment: Thank you!! 
what if i have to count the number of evens from the string?
for example: even = ['0','2','4','6','8']
evens= 4

Comment: Do you mean if you want to count the number of even numbers from the input? If so the variable evens will be holding the all the even numbers plus the brackets and quotation marks so, to all you  have to do is `len(evens)-4`

Comment: yes to count the even numbers, i tried but its not working

Comment: Really? Add this line to the end of the code I posted: `print('Evens : ' + str(len(evens)-4))` It should print the number of evens in the message.

Comment: this code is short and sweet 'msg = input("Please type: ")
print("Capital Letters: ", len([x for x in msg if x.isupper()]))
print("even numbers:", len([y for y in filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), msg) if int(y)%2 ==0]))'

Answer (score 0):

```
#to print the length of uppercase and print the even number present in the input

        msg = input("Please type: ")
        print("Capital Letters: ", len([x for x in msg if x.isupper()]))
        print("even numbers:", len([y for y in filter(lambda x: 
        x.isdigit(), msg) if int(y)%2 ==0]))

#long code to print the same:
            message = input("enter alphanumeric:")
            capitals = (sum(1 for c in message if c.isupper()))
            evens = ['0','2','4','6','8']
            evennumbers = []
            for x in range(0,len(message)):
                if(message[x] in evens):
                    evennumbers.append(message[x]) 
            capitals = str(capitals)
            evennumbers = str(evennumbers)
            print('Capitals : ' + capitals + ', Evens : ' + evennumbers')


#short code to print the length of Uppercase and even numbers in the input

        msg = input("Please type: ")
        print("Capital Letters: ", len([x for x in msg if x.isupper()]))
        print("even numbers:", len([y for y in filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), msg) if int(y)%2 ==0]))
```